# Does Chrome support X509v3 Permitted Name Constraints?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, google-chrome

I'm trying to set permitted name constraints on a private CA certificate. For example, I have the following constraints on my root certificate

```
X509v3 Name Constraints: critical
     Permitted:
       DNS:.mytestdomain.local
       DNS:mytestdomain.local
```

I've issued a certificate for another domain `anothertestdomain.local`. Both the Common Name and Subject Alternative Names are set to that domain. When testing validation for that certificate, OpenSSL and Firefox both fail with a Permitted Subtree Violation as expected. Chrome, however, accepts that certificate. Is this expected under Chrome?

I'm testing with Chromium on Linux.

Comment: I've tried this on IE11, Edge, Chrome on Windows, Firefox on Linux, Chrome on Linux and Chromium on Linux and all browsers complain if I have a name constraint in the final CA in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BetterTLS](https://nameconstraints.bettertls.com/) to check the Name Constraints support of various clients. It's open source and made by [the Netflix team](https://github.com/Netflix/bettertls).

> BetterTLS is a test suite for HTTPS clients implementing verification of the Name Constraints certificate extension.

It works for the browser and for non-browser clients (like Java and Python).

Answer (score 1):

According to this Chromium bug, what you're experiencing is intended functionality. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072083

> It sounds like you're placing nameConstraints on the root, which is
> not supported, not only in Chrome, but many major PKI implementations.
> That's because RFC 5280 does not require such support; imported root
> certificates are treated as trust anchors (that is, only the Subject
> and SPKI are used, not other extensions).
>
> If you place the constraints on the intermediate, this should work as
> intended. The net-internals log and full chain will help confirm, in
> which case, this may be WontFix/WorkingAsIntended.

I have not verified either way, but apparently the functionality you're after works (or worked) on Chromium on MacOS, but it seems like that's short-lived.

> I guess what threw me off is that macOS's SSL stack, the latest OpenSSL, and the latest stable Firefox were all were honoring nameConstraints on the root cert

> Yeah, the inconsistency between platforms is something we're aware of,
> and we're in the process of aligning Chrome platforms to the Chrome on
> Linux behaviour (that is, treating the root cert as a trust anchor).
> The Firefox change was a recent change, and partially motivated by a
> publicly-trusted CA request (a consortium of Greek universities)

Answer (score 0):

It should now work correctly.

> Enable anchor constraints enforcement on user added roots.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072083#c28